# Gmail drafts don't show recipient address in overview for new conversations

Tags: gmail

I have multiple drafts in my draft folder and some of them have the same subject. Unfortunately, when the draft is not part of an ongoing conversation, there is no indication of the recipient’s email address in the overview panel, even if it is already provided in the draft.

Is there any way or workaround to show the recipient in the overview, apart from copy-pasting it into the subject line?

Here's a screenshot of two drafts with the same subject, that is not part of a conversation. Followed by three drafts (where two have the same subject) that is part of an ongoing conversation and therefore the sender of the last mail is shown next to the red *Draft*.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no. A draft will always display the red text "Draft" in the overview instead of any saved recipients.

If the text is all the same in the drafts, I would just take the text and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for a recipient (ex. `Tom`) and you have a draft already saved for Tom, but it is showing as a red draft with no name, the draft will show up in the search results.

This won't help you see whom you still have to write to, but it will help you find the correct draft if they have the same subject.